How do you add a custom grid transformation to Proj's proj.db?
When migrating from PostGIS 2 to PostGIS 3.4, I found out that my old solution for overwriting the proj4text column in the spatial_ref_sys table did not work anymore.
The reason for this is that PostGIS now uses Proj's Proj.db before looking at it's own spatial_ref_sys table (https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/02/proj4-postgis.html).
I have tried adding adding the definition as a Proj init file (https://proj.org/en/9.4/resource_files.html#init-files), however, when debugging the transformation with projinfo -s 28992 -t 4326, the new transformation wasnt showing.
This is entry I added to the .init file.
<28992> +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.156160556 +lon_0=5.387638889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +nadgrids=/usr/share/proj/rdtrans2018.gsb +units=m +geoidgrids=/usr/proj/share/nlgeo2018.gtx +vunits=m +no_defs +type=crs <>
Since this didn't work, I wanted to add the definition to proj.db manually. In what tables do I need to add records in order to add my own custom transformation?
